# How to install matplotlib on OS X?

Tags: macos, python, homebrew

I want to install matplotlib on OS X. If possible, using homebrew.

I installed Python 2.7.1 using `brew install python`, I modified my path to use it
I installed pip using `brew install pip`
I installed numpy 1.5.1 using `pip install numpy`
I installed scipy 0.8.0 using `pip install scipy`

This is where it gets hairy. `pip install matplotlib` will [fetch the wrong version of matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555551/why-does-pip-install-matplotlib-version-0-91-1-when-pypi-shows-version-1-0-0), which is incompatible with the recent version of numpy.

The solution is to fetch the correct version of matplotlib manually:

```
pip install -f http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/matplotlib-1.0.1.tar.gz matplotlib
```

*But*, that version fails to compile since it can't find the freetype headers:

> In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:1:
>   src/ft2font.h:14:22: error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory

These headers are actually installed in `/usr/X11/include` as part of the X11 developer tools.

So, how can I make matplotlib use these headers?

Comment: Tried `brew install freetype` ?

Comment: Yeah. That package is not available. There is however a formula on github that provides it. Does not help, though.

Comment: `brew install freetype` worked for me as of 7-Nov-2012

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple answer is: You need to have `pkg-info` installed or else `setup.py` won't be able to find installed libraries.

Comment: How does one install `pkg-info`?

Comment: @bradley `brew install pkg-info`

Comment: Actually, I think it should be `pkg-config`, so `brew install pkg-config`. And don't forget to `brew link` it too.

Comment: I had pkg-config installed, but it didn't work. bradley.ayers solution worked for me.

Comment: Make sure the freetype2.pc file is in a location pkg-config knows to read

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that when the C extensions are compiled, required headers files aren't in the search path, and when they're being linked, shared libraries aren't in the search path either.

The following worked for me:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/X11/lib"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/X11/include/freetype2 -I/usr/X11/include/libpng12"
pip install matplotlib-1.0.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

I followed this [page's instructions](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/). I got stuck at

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib#egg=matplotlib-dev
```

Then I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
cd matplotlib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Checked my installation by typing in terminal:

```
python
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.__version__
print matplotlib.__file__
```

I got version 1.1.0 (as of this writing) and path /usr/local/Cellar/...

Comment: As of today, Matplotlib should be at version 1.0.1. I actually wrote something about this [here](http://www.daskrachen.com/2011/02/installing-pythonnumpyscipymatplotlib.html). Maybe you can find some useful information in there.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I meant 1.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Altneratively, you could use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/). With MacPorts this would be

```
sudo port install py27-matplotlib
```

which resolves the dependencies automatically.

Personally I used Macports to install python2.7 with matplotlib and it seems to works fine on 10.7. Fink is in the process of upgrading their internals to work with the new 10.7 build system.

Comment: I personally prefer Homebrew to MacPorts or Fink since it relies on system libs and is way more hackable. If you don't care about that, using MacPorts or Fink is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is, there's no freetype library. just simply brew it:

```
brew install freetype
```

Comment: brew install freetype -> 
Error: No available formula for freetype. Did the name change?

Comment: `brew install freetype` installs `libpng` too.

Answer (score 1):

with OS X 10.10.3 I fixed it with this commands

> brew install freetype libpng pkg-config

pkg-config fixed the issue!

After reading [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/) I manage to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Same problem using macports.  Fixed with:

```
sudo port install pkgconfig
```

as noio suggested for brew above.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work flawlessly on OS X 10.8.3
    http://penandpants.com/install-python/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this same reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451946/update-of-matplotlib-1-4-1-following-yosemite-update-using-pip-fails/26944051#26944051) but I think it can be of some interest in this discussion.

I got to install matplotlib on OSX 10.10 reading https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3713.
This is not a solution for pip users; just a way to install matplotlib on my mac waiting for a fix.

I downloaded sources for matplotlib 1.4.2,
changed line 960 in setupext.py as described in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3713/files :

```
'freetype2', 'ft2build.h',
```

becames

```
'freetype2', 'freetype2/ft2build.h'
```

and then compiled and installed with:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

These days, the easiest way is probably `conda install matplotlib`, using the `conda` package manager by continuum analytics.

Note that you can install and use `conda` without having to use the full Anaconda distribution. Just `pip install conda`, `conda init`, and you're good to go.