# cannot install matplotlib, freetype2 headers are ignored

Tags: installation, python, headers, pip

I want to install matplotlib via pip. There is a problem with freetype2.h

```
REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES

             numpy: 1.6.2

         freetype2: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)

                    * WARNING: Could not find 'freetype2' headers in any

                    * of '.', './freetype2'.
```

Somebody had a similar problem ( [How to install matplotlib on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/242190/how-to-install-matplotlib-on-os-x)), and it was suggested to install pkg-config first. I did that with macports, but I still get the same warning.

I used find to look for the headers, and they are definitely present in:

```
/opt/X11/include/ft2build.h
/usr/X11/include/ft2build.h
```

How can I use those files to install matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

I think you ought to be able to install the freetype headers (and also the Python ones, which will be needed too) in the expected place using:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev python-dev
```

But, for reasons I don't understand, after this, I still got a 'missing python.h' error when pip installing matplotlib. It didn't work for me until I had done:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

which installed & compiled craploads of junk (presumably for optional features of matplotlib?)

Comment: The `craploads of junk` worked for me as well.  ...and it truly was a crapload.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib require freetype. And you lost freetype c lib.
on Linux/Ubuntu, install freetype2 lib first

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6
```

Comment: Downvote because this is not sufficient. Pip installing matplotlib also requires at least libfreetype6-dev.